# Django - load new objects via ajax

Tags: django, django-models

In django app I need to periodically check for if new object of particular model are created.
I want to this by ajax.

I was thinking about something like this:
render current timestamp into template, load current objects.
Then, every x seconds do ajax request and ask for objects which are created later then this timestamp.

What do you think? Is there maybe a better way?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a way for the client to know whether something has changed in the server. Generally there are three ways to stimulate this subscriber/broadcaster, or pull/push, relationship. The first is Ajax long-polling, which is roughly what you described. The second is implemented via WebSocket, which unfortunately not all browser supports. The third is HTTP streaming, or a long polling at the HTTP level. All three are available in https://github.com/ziyan/django-comet

A newer technology is Webhooks, which allows you to subscribe to server changes via URL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook). Check it out here for an early Django adaptation: https://github.com/johnboxall/django_webhooks